# IP-адрес сайта

Tags: c#, winforms

Привет всем. Как по адресу сайта получить port сайта и вывести в текстовое поле на C#?

Answer (score 9):

Список ip адресов от днса:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("www.yandex.ru").AddressList
```

Как вытащить из коллекции и запихнуть в текстбокс думаю догадаетесь.

Чтобы вытащить порт из адреса думаю тоже додумаетесь? Можно изучить, и воспользоваться классом `Uri`:

```
new Uri("http://www.yandex.ru:9000").Port
```